# LibreOffice Calc: How to apply functions to columns?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

This is a rookie question. I need to use LibreOffice Calc for the first time, but unfortunately I don't have enough time to go through basic tutorials on right now.

I want to apply a function to (multiple cells of) a column and get the output in (the corresponding cells of) a different column. How do I do this?

Comment: Oh, wait, I got it: the parlance in Calc is "array functions", I just found out.

Comment: Go thru the tutorial or help file when you get a chance for a starting point, try something, and [edit] to indicate what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @Basil Welcome to [su]! If you have a solution based on array functions, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a formula in cell B1.

[image: first step -- formula in B1]

Then click on the small black square in the lower right hand corner of B1 and drag down, for example to B5.

[image: second step -- click and drag formula down to B5]

To use the menu instead, select B1 to B5 and go to `Sheets -> Fill Cells -> Down`.

To quickly apply the formula to the entire column, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868186/quickest-way-to-apply-a-formula-to-an-entire-column.

These are not [Array Functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions), because they just deal with a single value at a time.

Comment: I infer from your last statement that array functions would not work. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.  The question did not clearly state what is needed.  Array formulas are more difficult to understand and use, so avoid them when possible.

Comment: @jpaugh Well, I did do it with an array function yesterday, so it works. But, Jim K, thanks a lot for the answer, it'll help me to have the reference.

Comment: @Basil I'm glad you got it working. :-) If you post your solution as an answer, it may help someone in the future, in which case it may also earn you some rep.